# Last two digits of $x^y$, when the units digit of $x$ is $1$

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation, decimal-expansion

I want to know why the statement below is true.

Let $x$ and $y$ be two positive integers. And consider that: the units digit of $x$ is $1$; the ten's place digit of $x$ is $t$; and the units digit of $y$ is $u$. Then, the last two digits of $z=x^y$ can be obtained as follows:

- The unit's place digit of $z$ is $1$
- The ten's place digit of $z$ is the unit's place digit of $t\times u$

Comment: Other than the usual modular arithmetic crank turning, the other thing that will be useful here is the binomial theorem. (Besides that this result is not strictly correct, since it doesn't make sense for the tens place of, say, $31^5$ to be $15$.)

Comment: Text is too convoluted to understand. Besides, as Ian mentioned, the question doesn't make sense. Add an example. Also, the first sentence says that the base starts with 1; the second sentence says it ends with 1. Are they both true? Is that a typo?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be the number given by the digits: $a_n,...,a_2,a_1,a_0$. That is, $A = a_0 + 10\,a_1 + 100\,a_2 + ... + 10^n\,a_n$.

Let $B$ be the number given by the digits: $b_m,...,b_2,b_1,b_0$. That is, $B = b_0 + 10\,b_1 + 100\,b_2 + ... + 10^m\,b_m$.

If $\boxed{a_0 = b_0 = \mathbf{1}}$ (the unit digit of both numbers is $1$), the product $A \times B$ will be given by:

$C = A\times B = (\mathbf{1} + 10\,a_1 + 100\,a_2 + ... + 10^n\,a_n)\times B$

$C = [B] + [10\,(a_1+10\,a_2+...+10^{n-1}\,a_n)\times B]$

$C = [\mathbf{1} + 10\,(b_1 + 10\,b_2 + ... + 10^{m-1}\,b_m)] + [10\,(a_1+10\,a_2+...+10^{n-1}\,a_n)\times (\mathbf{1} + 10\,b_1 + 100\,b_2 + ... + 10^m\,b_m)]$

$\boxed{C = [1] + 10\,[a_1+b_1] \\+100\,[a_2 + ... + 10^{n-2}\,a_n + b_2+...+10^{m-2}\,b_m + (a_1+...+10^{n-1}\,a_n)(b_1+...+10^{m-1}\,b_m)]}$

This means that the units digit of $C$ is $1$ and the ten's place digit of $C$ is the units digit of $a_1+b_1$.

- If $y=1$ the statement is trivial;
- If $y=2$, we have $A=B=x$, so $a_1+b_1 \text{ mod }10 \equiv 2\,a_1 \text{ mod } 10$;
- If $y=3$, we have $A=x$ and $B=x^2$, which results in $a_1+b_1 \text{ mod }10 \equiv 3\,a_1 \text{ mod } 10$

For the general case, when the units digit of $x$ is $1$, the ten's place digit of $x^y$ will be the units digit of the product between $y$ and the ten's place digit of $x$. Since only the units digit of the product is relevant, we can operate only with the units digit of $y$.